# Does time cost of insert depend on the collection's size in MongoDB?

Tags: index, mongodb, insert

I've noticed that the inserts on my MongoDB are getting slower as the collection grows. The collection doesn't have any indexes.

I wasn't able to find anything about this topic in the official documentation. Is it a known behavior?

Comment: To make any suggestions I would like to know some more details, like - what is your cluster, collection size, the application, etc. How did you know that inserts are slower? What was the difference in your environment/application before the insert operations got slower? Questions like these ... The official documentation has details about some tools (Database Tools) which can be used to monitor and diagnose issues. You can also find some information at: [FAQ: MongoDB Diagnostics](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/).

Comment: I'll edit the question to provide more details, it was intentionally vague to avoid being prolix and result in tl;dr. The simplest question that is for me a sufficient starting point is: "is the cost of insert in mongo allways the same or does it depends on the collection's size?". From this answer I can at least understand if it's the case to go deeper or it's just normal.